# Including directories in Clion

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

Whenever I wanted to include a directory that was located outside of my project with Clion I would use the `-I somedir` flag. This time however, what I want to do is to have a hierarchy like this:

```
/project
   CMakeLists.txt
   /src
      /Graph
         Graph.h
         Graph.cpp
      /Dijkstra
         Dijkstra.h
         Dijstra.cpp
```

I want my code in a `/src` directory. And not only that, but also, for example, inside the file `Dijkstra.h` I want to include the Graph.h like this: `#include "Graph/Graph.h` and not like this: `#include "../Graph/Graph.h`.

If I only add an `-I src` flag, then if I am inside the `Dijkstra.h` file and I wanted to include `Graph.h`, I would have to write `#include "../Graph/Graph.h`, which is not what I want.

So I tried to also add `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(src)`. That fixed the problem above, however when tried to compiled, I got a linker error `undefined reference to...`.

So I tried adding the files one by one like this:

```
set(SOURCE_FILES
        src/Dijkstra/Dijkstra.h
        src/Dijkstra/Dijkstra.cpp
        src/Graph/Graph.h
        src/Graph/Graph.cpp)
add_executable(someprojectname ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

and that brought back the previous problem, where I had to include the files like this: `#include "../Graph/Graph.h"`.

How can I do this properly to get the behavior I want ?

Comment: i would suggest , you to use directory structure like this Graph/src/*.cpp , Graph/include/*.h , Dijkstra/src/*.cpp and Dijkstra/include/*.h.. Then try SET(GRAPH_INCLUDE_DIR Graph/include/) , SET(DIJKSTRA_INCLUDE_DIR Dijkstra/include/)  INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${GRAPH_INCLUDE_DIR} ${DIJKSTRA_INCLUDE_DIR })

Comment: Not clear question at all. If you use last variant and add `include_directories(src/Graph src/Dijkstra)` what happens?

Comment: The way I have suggested is better way making directory structure . .cpp in one directory and .h file in another directory. Why to mix these file in single directory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Command `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` **doesn't add** any **source file** for compile!

Instead, this command defines directories for **search header files**.

You need to list all **source** files in `add_executable()` call in any case:

```
include_directories(src)
set(SOURCE_FILES
    src/Dijkstra/Dijkstra.cpp
    src/Graph/Graph.cpp)
add_executable(someprojectname ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE:** @Tsyvarev's answer is correct. I've edited this answer to remove the incorrect part and keep the comments relating to `target_include_directories()`, but it should be viewed as additional to Tsyvarev's answer.

`INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(src)` will make the `src` directory get added as a search path to all targets defined from that point on. It does not add sources to any targets. The search path will be relative to the current source directory and CMake will adjust it as appropriate when descending into subdirectories via `add_subdirectory()`. While this is fine if that's what you want, as the project gets bigger and more complicated, you may find you would prefer to apply the include path settings to just some targets. For that, use [`target_include_directories()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html) instead:

```
target_include_directories(someprojectname "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src")
```

This will have the same effect, but it restricts the use of the added include path to just the `someprojectname` target. If you later define some other target which doesn't need the include path, it won't be added. This can help prevent situations like unexpected files being picked up if you have deep directory hierarchies and you re-use directory names in different places, for example).

The `target_include_directories()` command has additional benefits when applied to library targets because CMake has the ability to carry the include path through to anything you link against that library too. Doesn't sound like much, but for large projects which define and link many libraries, it can be a huge help. There are other target-specific commands which have similar benefits too. [This article](https://crascit.com/2016/01/31/enhanced-source-file-handling-with-target_sources/) may give you a bit of a feel for what is possible (disclaimer: I wrote the article). It is more focused on `target_sources()`, but the discussion around carrying dependencies through to other targets may be useful.

Comment: `include_directories()` **automatically** transforms all relative paths to absolute ones. See [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/include_directories.html) for more details.

Comment: Indeed you are correct! And I misunderstood the question (missed where include_directories() was being used). I'll leave my answer here for a while to allow those who already read it to see my correction, then I'll delete my answer. Thanks for the correction!