# How to set up sub directory includes in CMake/CLion?

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

This is similar to [Including directories in Clion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36885921/including-directories-in-clion), but after following the accepted answer there I made no progress.

I'm trying to edit a large OSS project in CLion. It does not use CMake, so CLion has generated a CMakeLists.txt file. When I open a source file, it is unable to resolve includes that use sub directories:

[image: Problem illustrated]

The file this screenshot is from is in the same "opto" subdirectory it is importing from. If I change the imports to not include "opto" it works fine, but I can't do that, since this is a major project and I'm just wanting to write a small patch:

```
$ find . -type f | wc -l
10532
```

I've added the file I'm importing directly to `add_executable` as suggested in the other answer:

```
# CMakeLists.txt
add_executable(hotspot
    [lots of other files]
    src/share/vm/opto/compile.hpp
)
```

And I've added the `opto` directory to `include_directories` as outlined in the second answer to the other question:

```
# CMakeLists.txt
include_directories(
    src
    src/share/vm/opto)
```

Neither is helping CLion resolve imports via the `opto` subdirectory.

What am I missing?

Comment: > since this is a major project and I'm just wanting to write a small patch

Then you'll have a better luck with a text editor instead of an IDE. Since it's a big project, you cannot use a trivial listfile, since it's a small patch, you are able to use the text editor. So I don't see, why not.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find the solution to this?

Comment: No, I gave up :(

Comment: Have you found a solution for this yet?

Answer (score 2):

Using **include_directories()** must do, but you have to mention each sub_directory **separately**. Below i have included two directories in the same way where one of it is sub_directory.

[image]

The Header files have successfully been detected by CLion.

[image]