# Why I cannot include SimpleITK.h can not be included in C++ after installation?

Tags: c++, clion, simpleitk

I have installed SimpleITK and tested with `ctest` successfully. Then,  I included the library in `.bashrc` as `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:~/softwares/vtk-itk/SimpleITK-build/lib`. For installation, I ran `make install` in `~/softwares/vtk-itk/SimpleITK-build/SimpleITK-build` and it was successfully installed. However, when I am trying to include `#include <SimpleITK.h>`, it seems that does know the installation path.

[image]

I am trying to write my code in Clion IDE, and even it does not show the simpleITK folder in `External Library` roots of the project.

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is not related to LD_LIBRARY_PATH as this is not a linking issue. You can learn more how to change/add include paths in CLion or with cmake from:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/quick-cmake-tutorial.html?_ga=2.94689947.663182776.1566473811-565224727.1566473811#include

[Including directories in Clion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36885921/including-directories-in-clion)

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206608335-How-can-I-specify-additional-include-files-

Basically it might be a missing include_directories( ) or something. I am not that familiar with simpleitk much but hope this general info helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I added `include_directories(/home/esomayeh/softwares/vtk-itk/SimpleITK-build/include/SimpleITK-1.1/)`, which has the header files inside to Cmake file. However, it is showing error: `main.cpp:(.text.startup+0xb4): undefined reference to `itk::simple::Image::Image....` for example here class `Image`. This error is shown for all the classes in the [helloWorld.cpp](https://simpleitk.readthedocs.io/en/master/Examples/HelloWorld/Documentation.html) , what is reason? how to resolve it

Comment: I believe that is a linking error, which could be because you have not specified the linking paths. You can use target_link_libraries to add the path where SimpleITK has their libraries( *.so,*.a files, usually in a subfolder named lib ). Here is a good answer that might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39598323/how-to-properly-link-libraries-with-cmake